# Is there a way to get all cells with the same value from a spreadsheet?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, file

I have provided an example below where I have multiples of the same value in `column B`, and lets assume the letters in  `column A` are files that exist in the same directory that this Excel sheet is in.

So I would like to create a Python script that for example will look at the the columns that have the same value, lets say `4`, and create a directory called `4`, and put all the files that correspond to the same value `4` from `column A`, in that file! So end result would be a directory named  `4` with the files `D`, `K` and `L` inside of it.

```
Column A    Column B
A           1
B           2
C           3
D           4
E           3
F           3
G           1
K           4
L           4
```

Comment: Hey @scape7575 ! What is the type of your sheet?

Comment: Hi @VidyaGanesh my sheet is .tsv, but I also have a .csv copy, thank you!!

Comment: Oh sorry! I am trying the code while replacing the directories for "df" and "directory" but it does not seem to be working, error in line 8 "KeyError: 'ColB'",thank you

Comment: Check the name of ColumnA and ColumnB in my case I used ColA and ColB

Comment: And I assumed the extensions of files A B C to be .txt which I've used as extensions in line 10

Comment: It works perfectly!! You're an absolute wizard sir. Many thanks to you!! @VidyaGanesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas` to do this. Here is an example I've tried using `.txt` files which are transferred to their corresponding folders 1 2 etc based on column2 values.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import shutil
directory= r"C:\Use\your\parent\directory\where\all\the\files\exist"
df=pd.read_csv("csv.csv")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    new_folder=os.path.join(directory,str(row['ColB']))
    os.makedirs(new_folder,exist_ok=True) #creates a new dir if folder with that particular number from ColB as name doesnot exist
    source=os.path.join(directory,str(row['ColA']+'.txt'))
    destination =os.path.join(directory,str(row['ColB']))
    # Move the file from source to destination based on the dataframe's ColA and ColB
    if os.path.isfile(source): 
        dest = shutil.move(source, destination) 
    else: 
        continue
```

What this does is moves `ColA` files from parent directory to corresponding folders created using `ColB` values

```
Folders | Files
1        -A
         -G
------------
2        -B
------------
3        -C
         -E
         -F
```

Comment: This output example is exactly what I meant to reach, perfect.

Comment: I added a loop to check if the file from ColA exists (need it for my usage), if anyone needed the same:     if os.path.isfile(source):
        dest = shutil.move(source, destination)
    else:
        continue

Comment: Good find. Thanks @scape7575

Answer (score 0):

You can use the os module to create directories and move files. You state that you have a spreadsheet, but I assume it is in some text-format? Then the code below should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
#Open data-file for reading
my_sheet = open('path/to/files/sheet.txt', 'r')
#Skip the header in data-file
my_sheet.readline()
#Read data-file line-by-line
for line in my_sheet:
    #Split line on white-space, directory is element[1]
    my_dir = 'path/to/files/'+line.split()[1]
    #Create directory if it does not exist
    if not os.path.exists(my_dir):
        os.mkdir(my_dir)
    #Split line on white-space, file is element[0], move file to dir 
    os.rename('path/to/files/'+line.split()[0], my_dir+'/'+line.split()[0])
```